# MVC - Populate Two Dropdowns From Database in Partial View with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Here's the visual of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

So basically what happens here is that you choose a name from the select on the left and a team from the select on the right, then click Submit Assignment and it adds a record.  (**This information is for reference so you can understand the context.  I don't need help with the database inserts or updates**.)

This is going to be a PartialView with a ViewModel.

I need to know how to populate those two dropdowns with separate lists.  I'm assuming those would be coming over in the ViewModel.

So in my main view, I have a call to the PartialView with RenderAction.

```
                    //The action       //The controller
@{Html.RenderAction("TeamAssignment", "TeamAssignment");}
```

The controller that gets called

```
public class TeamAssignmentController : Controller
    {
        MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult TeamAssignment()
        {
            //NEED A VIEW MODEL HERE TO PASS INTO THE PARTIALVIEW
            return PartialView();
        }
}
```

In the ViewModel I will need lists that populate the two drop downs.

The linq query on the left for Name would be this.

```
var nameList = (from p in db.Participant
                where p.ParticipantType == "I"
                select new {
                    p.ParticipantID,
                    p.IndividualName
                }).ToList();
```

The linq query on the right for Team would be this.

```
var teamList = (from p in db.Participant
                where p.ParticipantType == "T"
                select new {
                    p.ParticipantID,
                    p.TeamName
                }).ToList();
```

How can I pass that information into the PartialView and how do I populate the dropdowns with the ID for value and name for display text?

**UPDATE**

I belive this may be the ViewModel I need.  Is this correct?

```
public class TeamAssignmentViewModel
{
    //Need these ints for the updating and deleting
    public int IndividualParticipantID { get; set; }
    public int TeamParticipantID { get; set; }
    public List<Participant> NameList { get; set; }
    public List<Participant> TeamList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show you view, please. Not quite sure what your're trying to do, but i think you should use js for dynamic update View

Comment: There's nothing in the view that's relevant except for the call to the partial view.  `@{Html.RenderAction("TeamAssignment", "TeamAssignment");}`  Ignore the update stuff, I have that under control.  I just need to know how to send two object containing my lists for the dropdowns in a viewmodel from the controller to the partial view.

Comment: Why aren't you passing a model to your `PartialView`?

Comment: you can directly render partial view as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a viewmodel, populate it and pass it to your `PartialView`:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult TeamAssignment()
    {
        // Instantiate A VIEW MODEL HERE TO PASS INTO THE PARTIALVIEW
        MyCustomModel model = new MyCustomModel();
        model.nameList = (from p in db.Participant
            where p.ParticipantType == "I"
            select p).ToList();
        model.teamList = (from p in db.Participant
            where p.ParticipantType == "T"
            select p).ToList();

        return PartialView("TeamAssignment", model);
    }
```

**EDITED**: removed use of dynamic class in linq statements

The markup for the Dropdowns might look something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndividualParticipantID,
new SelectList(Model.NameList, "ParticipantID", "FirstName")

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndividualParticipantID,
new SelectList(Model.TeamList, "ParticipantID", "Team")
```

Comment: Though I suspect this example will fail as you can't assign an anonymous type to a custom model property. But when you update to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, that should be fixed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: David, can you show an example of how you have MyCustomModel set up?  Does it just contain two list properties like `public List<Participant> NameList { get; set; }` and `public List<Participant> TeamList { get; set; }`?

Comment: @madvora just those two properties (unless you require more in your partial).

Comment: David, I updated my post with the proposed ViewModel containing extra properties.  I am getting an error complaining about the ToList() after the queries in the controller though.
This was the error `Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#2>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.Models.Participant>'`

Comment: Sorry -- I not working with an IDE at the moment.  The problem you are encountering is with the `select new` in each query.  Posting an edit to my code now.

Comment: Edited code is posted -- I almost always use the 'dot' notation when I use linq-to-entities so hopefully I've got the syntax correct.

Comment: OK, the edit works without errors now, but please add 'p' after select, which is currently missing.

Comment: Thanks - I'm on the right track now, but I still need help with the PartialView and building those dropdowns.
I'm working on it, but if you have suggestions, please post.

Comment: Thanks David.  I updated your dropdown code because you were missing "Model." before NameList" and "TeamList".

So here's the final question, I really want to display FirstName + " " + "LastName" in the dropdown, but I wasn't able to build that field in the linq query since you took out the select new{ } part.  Can you tell my why that causes an error in this situation, and how can I get a concatenated field in there?

Comment: To claify, there isn't really an IndividualName field as I put in the original post.  I just used that for ease of explanation.

Comment: Rather than go deeper into conversation about anonymous types, why not just add a derived property called `IndividualName` to `Participant` which returns `FirstName + " " + LastName`

Comment: I thought I understood what you meant.  Under the Participant class I added `public string IndividualName {get; set;}` then added `public Participant(){IndividualName = FirstName + " " + LastName}` But when I call IndividualName in the dropdown, it's coming up blank.  I guess I'm doing this incorrectly.

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  In the model ------  
public string IndividualName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }            
        }  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by admitting that I haven't read everything posted, but I can help with passing data to the PartialView to be used as a model.

In your View, you can build the partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewName", currentItem,
   new ViewDataDictionary { 
      { "ExtraValue", Model.Count },
      { "SecondExtraValue", @ViewBag.ValueToPass });
```

Then in the PartialView, you can do this:

```
@model [Type of currentItem from above]
@{
   // I'm using var here for shorthand, whereas I do strong typing and cast in my codebase.
   var dataValue = ViewData["ExtraValue"];
   var secondDataValue = ViewData["SecondExtraValue"];
 }
```

Using this method you can pass in a model, as well as other values that may be needed for rendering.

Hope this helps. :)